# Decoders and Logic Gates

Tags: decoder, logic-gates

I have two questions.  First, I've been staring at this problem for over an hour and I'm stumped.  To be clear, I'm not looking for the answer, just some hints to get going would be helpful:

1) Using only three 2-to-4 decoders with enable and no other additional gates, implement a
3-to-8 decoder with enable. The inputs of the resulting 3-to-8 decoder should be labeled
as X2 X1 X0 for the code input and E for the enable input. The outputs should be labeled
Y7 Y6 Y5 Y4 Y3 Y2 Y1 Y0.

I definitely know how to use a 2-to-4 decoder, and how to use a 3-to-8 decoder, but how to create a 3-to-8 decoder using only three 2-to-4 decoders is stumping me.  I don't know where to begin making the connections.

Second, I have this circuit:

[image]

My next question has to do with a specific gate from this circuit:

[image]

I have never seen this gate and don't know exactly what to do with it.  Professor didn't go over it in class.  what is it?

Comment: I'm not going to help you with the first question (it really isn't hard).  The "what is this gate" question: it's a tri-state buffer.  The "side" input is the "enable"; if enable is asserted then the output follows the input, otherwise the output is high-impedance.  By the way, the diagram looks a little odd to me; the Dn outputs should be going to the inputs of the tri-state buffers, and X should be tied to all of the enable pins on the buffers.  The diagram has it the other way round.

Comment: High impedance?  He's never used that term.  What is that?

Comment: Also, could you give me some kind of hint for my first question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint for the 1st part: You need 8 outputs, this requires two 2-to-4 decoders.  What do you do with the 3rd 2-to-4 decoder?

Re the 2nd part of your question: "what is this gate?"

It's a tri-state buffer.  It's "tri-state" because the output can be one of three states: 0, 1 or Z.  I'll explain Z shortly.

The "side" input is the Enable.  If Enable is asserted (high or 1) then the output follows the main (data) input.  If Enable is not asserted (low or 0) then the output ignores the data input and becomes 'Z', or high impedance.

An output that is at 0 or 1 is actively driving the circuit.  It is effectively tied to power or ground through a switch.  If you were to attach two such outputs together and one was at 0 and the other at 1, then you would be joining power to ground - a short circuit.  This is... bad.

An output that is at Z doesn't do anything at all.  This is useful because you can tie any number of outputs that are at Z together and they won't misbehave.  Even better, you can select any one of the outputs and make it 1 or 0 and that one output will take control, overriding all of the Z's.

This is the basis of how computer buses work - lots of possible drivers, but only one of them enabled (driving 1 or 0) at any one time.

Comment: Let me see if I truly understand Z.  In our class we did k-maps.  In these k-maps we would have 0's 1's or X's, where X's where "Don't Cares".  Is this the same as your Z?

Comment: No.  Z is _not_ the same as X.

Comment: Check this It will help you. 
http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/COE/elrabaa/coe200/Lessons/Lesson3_4.pdf

Even 3X8 Decoder can be implemented using two 2X4 Decoder only with enable option. (Page 6-7)

Comment: As for question one.  I realized that two 2-to-4 decoders would be used for output.  From the first 2-to-4 decoder the outputs would be D0 = Y0, D1 = Y1, D2 = Y2, and D3 = Y3.  For the second 2-to-4 decoder the outputs would be D0 = Y4, D1 = Y5, D2 = Y6, D3 = Y7.  I'm getting confused most what to put into the third decoder, and how to use what comes out.

Comment: You are far better off in the long term working this out for yourself than getting an answer off the interwebs.

Comment: Oh, I got it.  I was getting caught up on have to use every output on the third gate.  Once I remembered I didn't have to do that I solved it.